# How to get Parameters of URL without refreshing the Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I have the following problem:

I am using the following function to retrieve the GET Parameters of an URL.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
function getParam(variable) {
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for ( var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                if (pair[0] == variable) {
                    return pair[1];
                }
            }
            return ("");
        }
});
```

For example I have the URL http://example.com/?radius=5&lat=31.312 and I want to have the value of "radius"

```
var radius = getParam("radius");
```

Problem: In the URL I can see that radius has the value "5" but when I run `console.log("radius " + radius);` only after refreshing the browser page the value is shown correctly.

Why isn't the value retrieved correctly while loading the page on the first time? Does anybody has an idea for fixing this?

I am getting the parameters by a submitted form from another html and I want to use them on the current html

Comment: Define function  outside of $(document).ready, then call your function.

Comment: no duplicate because the function is working. I need a solution for executing the function after the URL is loaded correctly and contains the values

Comment: Problem solved: I just put the function above into a setTimeout function. Sometimes it's easier as you would think

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard program for reading query string parameters:
http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm/2.html

Upload param.js, from the link at the bottom of that page, to your site and include it in a script element:

```
 <script src="[...]param.js"></script>
```

Regardless of what stage of loading the page is in you can call the function param() to read parameters, for instance:

```
var q = param();
var radius = q.radius;
```

Answer (score 0):

you van make function like this :

```
$.extend({
  getUrlVars: function(){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
      hash = hashes[i].split('=');
      vars.push(hash[0]);
      vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
  },
  getUrlVar: function(name){
    return $.getUrlVars()[name];
  }
});

// Get object of URL parameters
var allVars = $.getUrlVars();

// Getting URL var by its nam
var byName = $.getUrlVar('name');
```